# Flutter Text will not update further after Textfield input

Tags: flutter, dart

> I have arrow buttons to increase or decrease a variable `age` which work fine to update the `hintText`, but if I use the `TextField` widget to input a new value, it updates just fine, but after that the arrow buttons no longer function to further alter the age value in the `hintText`.

However, the value is still being updated behind the scenes and can be viewed with a `print` function.

Here's a simplified version of the code used:

```
TextField(
    onChanged: (val) {
          setState(() {
            age = int.parse(val);
          });,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: age.toString(),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xFF999999), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
)


Container(
      child: RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed: chngAge,
)


void chngAge() {
    setState(() {
      age++;
    });
  }
```

I'm wondering if after some text has been input into a text field that it is not longer `hintText` and thus cannot be updated in this way?

Comment: Can you post the whole code?

Comment: @Muhammad Noman No there's no space for the whole code which is spread across different files and such. This is all the necessary code. What is it you're not seeing?

Comment: reduce the code in a very simple example that we can run and test

Comment: @diegoveloper One person wants the whole code and now you want an even more simplified example. I already simplified it as much as I can. It's just a button and a textfield at the minute. Not sure what else I can remove?

Comment: let see, you assign  `age = val`;  val is String,  but in the method `chngAge`  you are using `age++`  , is string or int?

Comment: and one thing is the `hint` and another thing is the input of the text, are different things

Comment: It's an int and so gets changed to a string in the hintText. I guess val needs to be converted to an int at `age = val`..

Comment: Changed it to `age = int.parse(val)` but it didn't fix anything. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is changing the data of your `TextField` not the `hint` value, because when you write some text into your `TextField`, the hint disappears.

Here is an example I made :

```
class SampleText extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleTextState createState() => _SampleTextState();
}

class _SampleTextState extends State<SampleText> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
        onPressed: chngAge,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          controller: _controller,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFF999999), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void chngAge() {
    _controller.text = (int.parse(_controller.text) + 1).toString();
  }
}
```

You can get more info here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input

Comment: You don't have a `hintText` at all in your `TextField`? Do you still need `hintStyle` then?

Comment: you can add a `hintText` if you want (is not required), or remove hintStyle, hintText is a text that suggests what sort of input the field accepts (it should be constant).

Comment: So the way you have it there, will there be a value for `age` to begin with without the hintText?

Comment: TextEditingController can start with a String value  ... TextEditingController(text:"123") ;   https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/TextEditingController.html

Comment: Ok I see. So I could do without hintText in fact. Ok I'll try it tomorrow and get back to you, thanks for your help.

Comment: You seem to be missing `onChanged:` in the `TextField` otherwise the input value is not changing the value of the `age` variable.

Comment: you don't need to use onChanged value,  you can get the value using _controller.text wherever you want

Comment: I removed the 'age' variable , you don't need it if you are using TextEditingController :)